# update-grub finds two copies of all distros

Tags: grub2, grub2-mkconfig

Here is the output of update-grub on my system with an external (/dev/sdb) and internal (/dev/sda) SSD. Anybody know why I see two copies of each boot OS? Or how to start fresh?

```
    root@hp:~# update-grub
    Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
    Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
    Generating grub configuration file ...
    Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-22-generic
    Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-22-generic
    Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-19-generic
    Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-19-generic
    Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
    Found Manjaro Linux (21.2.0) on /dev/sda6
    Found Manjaro Linux (21.2.0) on /dev/sdb2
    Found Ubuntu MATE 21.10 (21.10) on /dev/sdb3
    Found Manjaro Linux (21.2.0) on /dev/sdb5
    Found UbuntuImp 21.10 (21.10) on /dev/sdb6
    =?why 2nd pass?=> Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
    Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
    Found Manjaro Linux (21.2.0) on /dev/sda6
    Found Manjaro Linux (21.2.0) on /dev/sdb2
    Found Ubuntu MATE 21.10 (21.10) on /dev/sdb3
    Found Manjaro Linux (21.2.0) on /dev/sdb5
    Found UbuntuImp 21.10 (21.10) on /dev/sdb6
    Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
    done
```

Comment: Added the following line:
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
and result is still two passes at UEFI Firmware:
`# update-grub
...Generating grub configuration file ...
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
`

Comment: could be some bugginess in latest Debian build of GRUB causing this issue: https://forum.siduction.org/index.php?topic=8482.msg68167#msg68167

Comment: you have multiple copies, actually three copies of Manjaro

Comment: Correct. I have Gnome, KDE and XFCE4 variants, the latter two are on /dev/sdb and Gnome is on /dev/sda. I should probably mention, the Grub on any/all of Manjaro performs correctly when running update-grub (OS_PROBER correctly identifies one and only one of each OS). Only Ubuntu and Ubuntu-MATE have the "echo" effect. And the convo about OS_PROBER being a security hole in the above link is from a **Debian** developer thread. Manjaro's flavor of grub is distinctly different from other distros, even including Arch, and they have removed grub-customizer from their app db.

Comment: See https://imgur.com/vggCqoa for a screen shot of grub-customizer. All are os-prober script derivatives, except the Ubuntu MATE where I ran the update-grub and the UEFI firmware (also probed by os-prober?).

Comment: Grub Customizer replaces grub scripts with its proxy files. `ls -l /etc/grub.d
` It normally backs those up into a sub-directory. But maybe you have duplicate grub scripts with both having executeable flag set? I prefer to manually edit grub and turn off 0s-prober. Then I add boot stanza's to 40_custom for the installs I want in grub. Grub2 is now turning os-prober off for security reasons also. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332570/how-do-i-stop-grub-from-scanning-particular-disks/1332664#1332664

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was replacing everything in /etc/grub.d with more vanilla items from another similar distro. I must have changed something there that caused os-prober to fire twice.